# Use library only if the DLL is available

Tags: c#, dll, proxy, nlog

I am using **NLog** in some of my libraries, and I would like for my libraries to work even if my user **does not** have the **NLog dll**.

My solution until now is to create an ILogger interface for the classes that I am using and to call the methods from NLog using reflection if the NLog dll was found.

The problem is that this method is sometimes very slow, causing an increased CPU usage of ~10% in my case (There are some places where I do a lot of logging).

Is there a more generic solution to my problem? maybe using emit so that I don't have such a performance hit? It just seems that there should be a simple solution to this problem.

Comment: Check only once and cache the result of the check instead of checking every time.

Comment: @SynerCoder: I already did that, my check has an expiration time of 500ms, but it seems to me that my bottleneck is the Invoke call.

Comment: If it's not a problem to customize the libraries a little you could try [LibLog](https://github.com/damianh/LibLog)

Comment: why the expiration time? it seems to me that if a library is there, it stays there.

Comment: @SynerCoder: I did this because of the long execution time, and because of the way deployment is done (it is a system that can push plugins to a running program). but you are right I still could have cached at least the values of the Is<Level>Enabled and I would have regained the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was similar solution to [LogLib](https://github.com/damianh/LibLog) (as posted by [pepo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3245057/pepo)).

The reflection part of my solution was causing the slowup, so I ended up creating compiled version of all the logger methods using linq expressions. This way I have a small increase in the execution time at startup, but faster execution time for the entire duration of the program (sometimes measured in days).

New version (faster):

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a method with one parameter of type TParam
/// </summary>
private static Action<object, TParam> CreateMethod<TParam>(Type targetType, string methodName)
{
    MethodInfo methodInfo = targetType.GetMethod(methodName, new Type[] { typeof(TParam) });

    ParameterExpression instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "inst");
    ParameterExpression msg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TParam), "p");
    Expression callExpression = Expression.Call(
        Expression.Convert(instance, targetType),
        methodInfo,
        msg);
    Expression<Action<object, TParam>> methodExpression = Expression.Lambda<Action<object, TParam>>(callExpression, instance, msg);
    Action<object, TParam> method = methodExpression.Compile();
    return method;
}

/// <summary>
/// Creates a getter with the return type TReturn
/// </summary>
private static Func<object, TReturn> CreateGetter<TReturn>(Type targetType, string propertyName)
{
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = targetType.GetProperty(propertyName);

    ParameterExpression instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "inst");
    Expression callExpression = Expression.Property(
        Expression.Convert(instance, targetType),
        propertyInfo);
    Expression<Func<object, TReturn>> methodExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, TReturn>>(callExpression, instance);
    Func<object, TReturn> property = methodExpression.Compile();
    return property;
}
```

using this kind of helpers i store the compiled version of the methods:

```
Action<object, string> trace = CreateMethod<string>(logger.GetType(), "Trace");
Func<object, bool> isTraceEnabled = CreateGetter<bool>(logger.GetType(), "IsTraceEnabled");
```

And in my wrapper, I call the methods like this:

```
isTraceEnabled(logger);
trace(logger, "message")
```

This is much more complicated than the old version, where i would just declare the logger as dynamic

```
dynamic logger = ....
// ...
logger.IsTraceEnabled;
logger.Trace("message");
```

But in my special case the speedup is noticeable. Now I only have a slowup of around 1%. I did some more measurements and it turns out the actual reason behind it is the extreme number of calls to check if Trace is enabled. In the release version Trace is turned off, but I still have around 14 logger who's IsTraceEnabled property I have to constantly probe.

In hindsight I could have cached the values of the IsEnabled properties and gain a similar startup, but oh well... I noticed it a bit to late.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your solution is the only one possible, that is use of reflection.
Indeed, reflection is more expensive in terms of computation.

Comment: I think that an emit solution is also possible, something like: Invoke for creating the objects, and emit for calling the proxy methods. The problem is that I am not fit with the il emit magic, and I was hoping there is a solution that will generate the code for me.